# How to apply elements in common in several HTML pages

Tags: html, css, templates

I have a page which has a top and a bottom is common for all pages.

I'd had copied the top and bottom and paste them to all new pages created on the site and an idea came to me that this is not a good practice.
Then I thought of the following problem: if I add edit, add, or remove something in the top or bottom, I will have to make this change for all pages on the site.

Is there any way to create a template with these elements in common, in this case top and bottom, and then all pages that are created will be based on this template?
Hence, if I need to edit something, I just edit it in the template that reflects on all pages.

example:
[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any framework, the easiest way that I can think of to achieve this would be to use PHP, but you will need a server application like XAMPP, LAMPP to run your application locally.

Simply, create 2 files, header.php and footer.php, these files will have the top and bottom parts of your HTML codes. And the other files will will have names like, index.php, about.php etc.

In the index.php put this code whereever you want the top part of your code to be rendered (in your case, the first line of index.php),

```
<?php include header.php; ?>
```

and for the bottom part (which will be at the very end of the index.php),

```
<?php include footer.php; ?>
```